# Traversing files within running jar (in Java 7)

Tags: java, jar, nio, nosuchfileexception

Is it possible to use the new `Java 7 NIO file library` to traverse a directory tree within a jar in the same way you would on a normal filesystem?

I've got a directory structure I'm reading images from which I'd like to be able to run both in the normal way and also by packaging it as a jar file and running with `java -jar.`

It seems like the new FileSystem class as well as FileVisitor should be able to achieve this, but there is little documentation on how this can work within a jar. I've tried the following:

```
private static final FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
public static final String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
Files.walkFileTree(fileSystem.getPath(workingDir, "\res\training\"), new FileVisitor<Path>() {
    ...
    });
```

This works fine for running from an IDE or by command-line, but when packaged as a jar gives errors similar to:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:  C:\Users\*rest of path*\*jar_folder*\res\training
>   at util.Main.(Main.java:47) Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\*rest of path*\*jar
>   folder*\res\training

Evidently it is attempting to find the files in the directory the jar is running in, rather than inside the jar itself.

Comment: Why? Don't you already know what's in the JAR file? If not, why not?

Comment: I know what's in the jar as far as I know the structure is /A/B/... where A is the parent directory, which could have several B directories and ... is the files in those directories. I'm performing image analysis and need to be able to add sets of images easily (i.e. a new B directory with the images within), so don't want to have to hardcode new paths in every time I add more images.